# Architecture of PHP based Production environment for push notifications on iOS

Tags: php, ios, push-notification

I'm ready to move my app and push notification platform into production soon, I have two .php scripts that need to be running the whole time (one checking for notifications to be sent and making the payload, the other opening a connection to Apple's push notification service and sending.

I've never run anything like this in prod, in dev I just used terminal to execute the .php, and mamp for the web server (php web API), so my question is how should I run this in prod? Is this style ok, ie. just running .php in the terminal and sticking with MAMP, or do I need to implement this differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As outlined above is how i'm now running prod, with nagios on linode.